# Keyboard.FocusedElement is null in UnitTest

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I'm trying to set the focus of a wpf control with:

```
[TestClass]
[TestFixture, Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
public class OnEnter_MoveFocus_Test
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() != ApartmentState.STA)
        {
            throw new ThreadStateException("The current threads apartment state is not STA");
        }
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMoveFocus()
    {
        TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox() { Name = nameof(TextBox1), Focusable=true };
        var result = TextBox1.Focus(); //results in false
        Keyboard.Focus(TextBox1);
    }
}
```

`TextBox1.Focus();` returns false (obviously `TextBox1` is Focusable and Enabled)  and when using `Keyboard.Focus(TextBox1);` the `Keyboard.FocusedElement` is still `null`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: A `TextBox` you create doesn't belong to any visual tree and cannot be managed by the `FocusManager`. So obviously this won't work. You have to add your `TextBox` to a visible container first.

Comment: You can't perform these sorts of UI tests from within a typical unit test.  Take a look at the White framework from TestStack (there is a group for this on SO) for a method of performing this type of testing.